# Extending Request type to add Redis Client

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, redis

I am trying to create this `api.ts` file and put the redis client on the request to pass it to all the routes. But I am getting an error that there is no client on the Request>. How do I extend the request type and put it on the request in TypeScript?

Here is my file

```
import { version } from '../../package.json';
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export default ({ config, client } : any) => {
    let api = Router();
    api.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        req.client = client;
        next()
    })
    api.get('/', (_req, res) => {
        res.json({ version });
    });
    return api;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
req['client'] = client;
```